# Example of alpha-conversion needed in Mincaml

Tags: compiler-construction, ocaml

I had a course about functional programming in *ocaml / mincaml* and we talked about alpha-conversion. If I get it well, the goal of *alpha-conversion* is to syntactically make a difference between two different variables which could have been assigned the same name in different parts of the code, right?

My issue is that our teacher was going pretty fast assuming we all had a good background on this topic and especially saying "**You will easily find MinCaml programs needing alpha-conversion to give correct answers.**"

I have been searching but I don't really see though, would you have an example in mind, or a good documentation online to help me understand better this concept with some examples where *alpha-conversion is **indeed needed***?

Thank you very much.

N.B. If someone has a better ideas with tags, I can't add either "mincaml" or "alpha-conversion" so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alpha-conversions makes implementation of some compiling processes easier and clearer.

For example, when MinCaml eliminates unnecessary definitions ([`elim.ml`](https://github.com/esumii/min-caml/blob/master/elim.ml)), it searches free variables of an expression ([`KNormal.fv`](https://github.com/esumii/min-caml/blob/master/kNormal.ml)) to check whether we can safely eliminate a definition.

If we can't assume each variables have its individual names, this process needs a further search. By doing the alpha-conversion before the eliminations, we can skip this and write the process with simple codes.

Comment: Hmm.. Okay I think it is a bit clearer now, but then my teacher's question about a MinCaml program failing without alpha-conversion, he only meant a program with different variables called similarly? This answer seems too simple, I think I still miss something

Comment: @RobinS. If we simply remove alpha-conversions from MinCaml, then yes, MinCaml fails to generate a correct binary ("answer"?) because some processes are implemented on a premise of an existence of alpha-conversions. But is this actually what your teacher wanted to mean? I cannot to be sure; maybe it's better to ask him directly and self-answer about that.